# How do I access HTTP POST data from meteor?

Tags: json, api, meteor, http-post, iron-router

I have an Iron-router route with which I would like to receive lat/lng data through an HTTP POST request.

This is my attempt:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('serverFile', {
    path: '/receive/',
    where: 'server',

    action: function () {
      var filename = this.params.filename;
      resp = {'lat' : this.params.lat,
              'lon' : this.params.lon};
      this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
      this.response.end(JSON.stringify(resp));
    }
  });
});
```

But querying the server with:

```
curl --data "lat=12&lon=14" http://127.0.0.1:3000/receive
```

Returns `{}`.

Maybe `params` doesn't contain post data? I tried to inspect the object and the request but I can't find it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [connect framework](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/) within iron-router uses the bodyParser middleware to parse the data that is sent in the body. The bodyParser makes that data available in the `request.body` object.

The following works for me:

```js
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('serverFile', {
    path: '/receive/',
    where: 'server',

    action: function () {
      var filename = this.params.filename;
      resp = {'lat' : this.request.body.lat,
              'lon' : this.request.body.lon};
      this.response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 
                                    'application/json; charset=utf-8'});
      this.response.end(JSON.stringify(resp));
    }
  });
});
```

This gives me:

```
> curl --data "lat=12&lon=14" http://127.0.0.1:3000/receive
{"lat":"12","lon":"14"}
```

Also see here:
http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/bodyParser.html

Comment: **request.body** is what I was looking for.. Thanks!