# Webhook for Mailgun POST?

Tags: meteor, webhooks, iron-router, mailgun

I am trying to store email messages as JSON (as parsed by Mailgun) in a Mongo.Collection through a Mailgun webhook. I set up an iron-router server-side route to handle the request, but `this.request.body` is empty. I am using Mailgun's "Send A Sample POST" to send the request, and the POST looks fine using e.g. http://requestb.in/. I was hoping that request.body would have the data, as mentioned in [How do I access HTTP POST data from meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691001/how-do-i-access-http-post-data-from-meteor). What am I doing wrong?

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('insertMessage', {
    where: 'server',
    path: '/api/insert/message',
    action: function() {
      var req = this.request;
      var res = this.response;

      console.log(req.body);
      ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that Mailgun sends a multipart POST request, e.g. it sends "fields" as well as "files" (i.e. attachments) and iron-router does not set up a body parser for multipart requests. This issue is discussed [here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/909) and [here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1003) on iron-router's Github Issues. I found [this](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/909#issuecomment-61748074) comment particularly helpful, and now I can parse Mailgun's sample POST properly.

To get this working, in a new Meteor project, I did

```
$ meteor add iron:router
$ meteor add meteorhacks:npm
```

In a root-level `packages.json` I have

```
{
    "busboy": "0.2.9"
}
```

which, using the `meteorhacks:npm` package, makes the "busboy" npm package available for use on the server via `Meteor.npmRequire`.

Finally, in a `server/rest-api.js` I have

```
Router.route('/restful', {where: 'server'})
  .post(function () {
    var msg = this.request.body;
    console.log(msg);
    console.log(_.keys(msg));
    this.response.end('post request\n');
  });

var Busboy = Meteor.npmRequire("Busboy");

Router.onBeforeAction(function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    var body = {}; // Store body fields and then pass them to request.
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on("field", function(fieldname, value) {
      body[fieldname] = value;
    });
    busboy.on("finish", function () {
      // Done parsing form
      req.body = body;
      next();
    });
    req.pipe(busboy);
  }
});
```

In this way I can ignore files (i.e., I don't have a `busboy.on("file"` part) and have a `this.request.body` available in my routes that has all the POST `field`s as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is the right syntax. Have you tried using `Router.route` ?

```js
Router.route('insertMessage', 
  function () {
    // NodeJS request object
    var request = this.request;

    // NodeJS  response object
    var response = this.response;

    console.log("========= request: =============");
    console.log(request);

    // EDIT: also check out this.params object
    console.log("========= this.params: =============");
    console.log(this.params);

    // EDIT 2: close the response. oops.
    return response.end();
  }, 
  {
    where: 'server',
    path: '/api/insert/message'
  }
);
```

Comment: I see this.request object, but it's huge, and it's unclear where the relevant info is. And this.params doesn't have anything helpful in it. [This (link)](http://requestb.in/1gi3bfc1?inspect) is the kind of data I expect to extract easily (http://requestb.in POST bin that probably expires in 48 hours).