# Meteor how to receive HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, meteor, twilio, iron-router

I have a Meteor app that I want to receive HTTP requests with, but I'm not sure how to set it up? Specifically I'm trying to receive data on my web app from text messages through Twilio. I've looked at a package called Iron Router, would that be the correct way to go about it?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access HTTP POST data from meteor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691001/how-do-i-access-http-post-data-from-meteor)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Looks like you're on the right lines there with Iron Router. Here is a good blog post that might help you along the way: [Implementing WebHooks with Meteor](http://u2622.ca/blog/2014/08/17/implementing-web-hooks-with-meteor).

Let me know if that helps.