# Integrating Payumoney With Meteor App

Tags: meteor, payumoney

I am trying to integrate PayuMoney payment gateway into my Meteor App. The process involves sending a POST request to a external url(payu url) and also redirecting the user to it. The user completes the payment on PayUmoney's site and once done, the PayUmoney site redirects back to a url(provided by me) with parameters passed as POST.

What I have done currently, 
To post the form, I have allowed the default behavior of the form. I have defined the method as POST, with the target URL and all input parameters as hidden.

However, I am unsure on how to accept the variables after the tranasaction. I tried this method: [How do I access HTTP POST data from meteor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691001/how-do-i-access-http-post-data-from-meteor) but, this didn't work.

Technical Integration Document (Pay U Money): https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.uservoice.com/assets/074/080/407/original/PayUMoney_Technical_Integration_Document.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJF4UXUF6KJMEJFQQ&Expires=1519543396&Signature=ASnFquJkmCwQSMfx93w913MjZPk%3D

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about accepting the response from PayUMoney, `meteorhacks:picker` is a great library for setting up an API.  If you follow along with [this guide](https://themeteorchef.com/recipes/building-an-error-logger/), you'll get taken through all the steps of setting an endpoint up that can accept a cross-origin POST request.

Comment: Thnaks! This was helpful.